# How do I stop BeeLine from automatically coloring every website?

Tags: google-chrome-extensions

BeeLine seems quite a cool Chrome extension yet it's extremely annoying that it automatically start on every website I visit and I have to disable it for every particular website. I would really like it to work the opposite way - only do its job when I trigger it manually. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about the [BeeLine Reader Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/beeline-reader/ifjafammaookpiajfbedmacfldaiamgg?hl=en), there's no way to do what you're asking (at least in the free version I tried). You'd have to turn it off for every individual site you want it to not color.

You could use another extension that has the same effect built in, such as [Just Read Premium](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/just-read-premium/dpamdgmnffodphoamchpmbclkpmccjga/reviews) which would provide additional features you may like as well. Just Read only runs when you tell it to (though you can tell it to run automatically if you give it a list of domains). It does have an annual fee to use it though.

<sub>**Disclaimer: I am the creator of Just Read.**</sub>

Comment: Cool, thanks! I've done some googling and couldn't find a single app that would do what BeeLine Reader does, I was already going to implement it as a stand-alone app myself...

Comment: Ya, I haven't seen it in any other extensions either. I came across BeeLine while researching reader extensions and thought it was a good idea. I actually use a different (less intensive) method of doing it than what their extension does. You could take [my CodePen demo](https://codepen.io/Zeaklous/pen/GGXVwd) and make your own extension out of it pretty easily if you wanted to.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the autorun slider to the most conservative setting, and then it will rarely run on its own. You can then just trigger it manually as you wish.